# Android Studio 3.01 too slow

Tags: android-studio

I know it is a returning question but I do not understand.
I have a decent machin (I think that is: i7(8 core) CPU, 16Gb RAM, and SSD with a lot of space), I have created custom VM (-Xms1G, -Xmx4G) and custopm properies file, I have turned on offline and created .gradle file in my home directory (org.gradle.daemon=true, org.gradle.parallel=true) but this IDE is still too slow. A beginner project takes 1m 27s. Why, please?

Comment: I know I am a very beginner in Android Studio but why, please? It's too easy downgrade my question without any comments, isn't it.

Comment: Problem solved. The antivirus software caused the slowdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved. The antivirus software caused the slowdown.